# Be'er Hagoleh- looking to buy

Tags: jewish-books, maharal

Does anybody know where I could buy a Be'er Hagoleh written by the Maharal in Hebrew. I can only find English translations of it.

Comment: https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/?q=%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8+%D7%94%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://mysefer.com/Hebrew/Rabbi-Yehudah-Loew-Maharal-of-Prague/Maharal--Beer-Hagolah-3-Vol.-__p-73-259-1764.aspx) is the best version of the Be'er Hagolah with much needed explanations from Rav Yehoshua Hartman Shlit"a.

Comment: What makes it the best version? Which other versions have you compared it to?

Comment: There are versions with older print - https://seforimcenter.com/HEBREW-Books/Rabbi-Yehudah-Loew-Maharal-of-Prague/Sifrei-Maharal-Torah-vChaim-Edition--volumes-1-14__p-73-259-871.aspx

Comment: As well as a newer print - https://seforimcenter.com/HEBREW-Books/Rabbi-Yehudah-Loew-Maharal-of-Prague/Set-Maharal-miPrague-13-vol.--Tiferet-Edition__p-73-259-13721.aspx

Comment: The Mechon Yerushalayim edition I listed above brings the many textual variances (נוסחאות) from different versions, but most importantly it illuminates the words/ideas of the Mahara"l from comments of the Mahara"l himself in different places, as well as other contemporary Gedolim who would expound on the ideas of the Mahara"l like Rav Yitzchak Hutner or Rav Moshe Shmuel Shapiro ZT"L. These other editions don't have any of these benefits.

Comment: You can preview the sefer online here - https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&pagenum=1&book=150643

Comment: @moshe please edit your comments into your answer to make it self-contained

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough money and are willing to splurge for the complete writings, the Berkovitz edition is also an excellent choice. The link follows:

https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=13721&strReferer=search&PPGR=4